# Any strong consistent tutorials for beginners?

Tags: modeling, animation

1st I hope this is the right place, because it's a little hard to find a place where you can ask simple question. Like there is no registration in blender forums and I don't know why.

2nd I have a question and I hope get good and informative answer to it.

So. Hi again. I was looking in google and youtube for good tutorials for beginner. I mean not "how to create a box" or "animate your box". I was looking some strong and new tutorials like "how to create animated girl" or "how to create a realistic weapon and texture it". But I didn't found anything good. I found only scattered tutorials without any explanations. Well "Blender Guru" I liked in youtube. But it's too little tutorials there. I'm ready to pay some money monthly like 10$ you know. And I saw I can pay it in blender clouds. I tried to find some free information in there where to start and etc. But I didn't found any consistent tutorials like what you can do when you create this girl or this weapon. Like in example "If you create a weapon not let's go animate it to shoot!" you know. So I wan't to ask should I spend money in blender clouds? Or you know better place? Any information from you practice would be most amazing thing in today for me! So thank you and waiting for answers in this place :). I hope this place is really good! :) BTW sorry for bad English!

EDIT: from some comments of you i found in resources blender101, is it right place would be? Because it cost a little.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15355/resources-for-blender

Comment: it depends what you would like to learn. You may be interested in https://cgcookie.com. Also there are some courses on udemy: https://www.udemy.com/courses/search/?q=blender. Lynda/pluralsight have resources on blender as well. But I suspect for most blender users, it is a mixture of picking up tips up from various youtube videos, blenderartists.org resources, articles from blendernation, and some paid/premium content.

Comment: so blender101 would be good place from what i found from links, right?